# How to remove pills from lightning-pill-container?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I believe I have identified an error in the [LWC documentation for lightning-pill-container](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-pill-container).

The javascript reads as follows:

> Copying this into an org, the statement "this.items = items.splice(index, 1);" throws an error because "[items is not defined]".

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class Basic extends LightningElement {
    @track items = [
        {
            label: 'a1'
        }, 
        {
            label: 'a2'
        }, 
        {
            label: 'a3'
        }
    ];

    handleItemRemove (event) {
        const name = event.detail.item.name;
        alert(name + ' pill was removed!');
        const index = event.detail.index;
        let items = this.items;
        items.splice(index, 1);
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

Note that in addition to "items" not being defined, the code is wrong because splice has a side effect of modifying the array, but the return value is the removed elements.

If I rewrite the `handleItemRemove` function as follows, it does not throw an exception, but it also does not remove items when clicked (the alert is correctly displayed however).

```
handleItemRemove (event) {
    const name = event.detail.item.name;
    alert(name + ' pill was removed!');
    const index = event.detail.index;
    let items = this.items;
    items.splice(index, 1);
    this.items = items;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replacing the offending line with one that uses filter works:

```
this.items = this.items.filter(item => item.name !== event.detail.item.name)
```