# LWC lightning-pill-container with href attribute fires remove event twice

Tags: lightning-web-components

When using a pill container (lightning-pill-container) containing pills with `href` attribute to link to a URL the itemremove handler seems to fire twice.

[Example in Playground is provided here.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/2_j484laY/4/edit)

**Expected behaviour**: The onitemremove event should only fire once and remove only the pill which is being clicked

**Actual behaviour**: The onitemremove event fires twice with the same event.detail.index and removes two pills - the original pill plus whatever pill happens to now occupy the same index in the array after filtering/splicing

NB: this behaviour only seems to occur when the href attribute is present in the pill collection. If you remove this attribute the itemremove event behaves correctly

Also please note this is a different issue to that reported in the following questions as it relates specifically to the href attribute being present:

[how-to-remove-pills-from-lightning-pill-container](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262868/how-to-remove-pills-from-lightning-pill-container)

[lwc-lightning-pill-container-does-not-redraw-when-adding-items](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/264018/lwc-lightning-pill-container-does-not-redraw-when-adding-items)

The example code is shown below:

HTML template

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="lightning-pill-container">
        <div class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
            <lightning-pill-container items={items} 
                onitemremove={handleItemRemove}>
            </lightning-pill-container>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS File

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    @track items = [
        {
            label: 'a1', href: 'www.google.com'
        }, 
        {
            label: 'a2', href: 'www.amazon.com'
        }, 
        {
            label: 'a3', href: 'www.news.com'
        }
    ];

    handleItemRemove(event) {
        const index = event.detail.index;       
        const _item = this.items;
        _item.splice(index, 1);        
        this.items = [..._item];        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug. However this is happening only when the items are modified in same transaction. So, as a work-around until this bug is fixed, we can separate the transaction in Javascript using `setTimeout`:

```
handleItemRemove(event) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.items = this.items.filter((item) => item.label !== event.detail.item.label);
    });
}
```

[Playground Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/2_j484laY/8/edit)

Comment: Thanks - that's a great workaround!